# Windows Scheduled Tasks : PHP tasks / Last Run result 0x15

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a couple of PHP scripts that I need to run a couple of times / day on my Windows environment. I have created multiple scheduled tasks with the Windows Task Scheduler, they are all configured exactly the same way.

The trigger is time based (ex: every 6 hours). The action is almost the same too:

- start a program: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
- Add arguments: http://localhost:8000/prices/cron.php?shop=bolbe

This particular examples works well and ends with a 0x0 code in the last run result. All the others tasks end up in 0x15 while the only things that are different are:

- trigger : different time
- action: only the parameter shop= changes

When I look in the Windows Task Manager I see multiple instances of chrome.exe but none of them is visible on my desktop which means that chrome is executed but for some reason it doesn't execute the php script.

If I execute the php scripts manually, they all work fine.

Any idea ?

Thanks